# undeclared identifier UBoxComponent

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I have created an Actor C++ component "PickUp". But there are few lines that are throwing errors. I have declared UShapeComponent, UStaticMeshComponent, USceneComponent, OnPlayerEnterPickUpBox() functions

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "PickUp.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class YT_API APickUp : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    APickUp();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    USceneComponent* PickUpRoot;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UStaticMeshComponent* PickUpMesh;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UShapeComponent* PickUpBox;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnPlayerEnterPickUpBox(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult );
};
```

This is the cpp files. Where all the code is written in constructor

```
#include "PickUp.h"


// Sets default values
APickUp::APickUp()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    PickUpRoot = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("PickupRoot"));
    RootComponent = PickUpRoot;

    PickUpMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("PickupMesh"));

    PickUpMesh->AttachToComponent(PickUpRoot, FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale);


    PickUpBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("PickupBox"));
    PickUpBox->SetWorldScale3D(FVector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    PickUpBox->bGenerateOverlapEvents = true;
    PickupBox->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &APickUp::OnPlayerEnterPickupBox);
    PickUpBox->AttachToComponent(PickUpRoot, FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APickUp::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APickUp::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

void APickUp::OnPlayerEnterPickUpBox(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult )
{
    Destroy();
}
```

When I try to run this I get following errors:

```
Info Setting up Mono
Info /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.16/Engine /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.16/Engine/Binaries/Mac
Info Compiling game modules for hot reload
Info Parsing headers for YTEditor
Info   Running UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/abhimanyuaryan/Documents/Unreal Projects/YT/YT.uproject" "/Users/abhimanyuaryan/Documents/Unreal Projects/YT/Intermediate/Build/Mac/YTEditor/Development/YTEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Info Reflection code generated for YTEditor in 7.82594 seconds
Info Performing 2 actions (8 in parallel)
Info [1/2] Compile PickUp.cpp
Info /Users/abhimanyuaryan/Documents/Unreal Projects/YT/Source/YT/PickUp.cpp:20:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UBoxComponent'; did you mean 'RootComponent'?
Info     PickUpBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("PickupBox"));
Info                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Info                                        RootComponent
Info Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/Actor.h:463:19: note: 'RootComponent' declared here
Info         USceneComponent* RootComponent;
Info                          ^
Info /Users/abhimanyuaryan/Documents/Unreal Projects/YT/Source/YT/PickUp.cpp:20:17: error: no matching member function for call to 'CreateDefaultSubobject'
Info     PickUpBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("PickupBox"));
Info                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Info /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.16/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/Object.h:81:15: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'TReturnType'
Info         TReturnType* CreateDefaultSubobject(FName SubobjectName, bool bTransient = false)
Info                      ^
Info /Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.16/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/Object.h:95:15: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'TReturnType'
Info         TReturnType* CreateDefaultSubobject(FName SubobjectName, bool bTransient = false)
Info                      ^
Info 2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined PickupBox as a UShapeComponent* in the header, yet you are casting it to a UBoxComponent in the CPP.

Change the header to match the variable type you ultimately want (in other words, change the header to UBoxComponent* PickupBox).

Addendum: UShapeComponent is a parent of UBoxComponent. It does not define shapes itself, that is why you must use (and cast to) the child class to detect collisions. See https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UShapeComponent/index.html